# Vertically center image with respect to longtable paragraph

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

I have a `longtable` with some longer text in one column and an image in another column. I need the image to be vertically centered. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe} % blindtext, example image
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} % for m column type

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|m{2cm}|}
    \blindtext &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe} % blindtext, example image
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} % for m column type

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|m{5cm}|p{2cm}|}% <-- changed
    \blindtext &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Can you please explain why it works? I thought `m` was supposed to center cells...

Comment: yes, but to baseline of cells in neighborhood colums. so in your case the baseline of the first cell (`p` type) was on the top ... i only move it to vertical center (`m` type).