# vertically center image in longtable

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, longtable

I have a longtable with \cline borders. Unfortunately, the image in the second column is not vertically centered. I even fail in changing the vertical position any way. I found this similar question: [Vertically center image with respect to longtable paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388737/vertically-center-image-with-respect-to-longtable-paragraph)

But changing p and m parameter doesn't seem to have an influence.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{m{0.06\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}}
%    \begin{longtable}{p{0.06\textwidth}m{0.3\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}m{0.05\textwidth}} % doesn't work either
        Index & Figure & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla\\
        \cline{2-8}
        1      & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a} & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
        \cline{2-8}
        2      & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a} &  bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla  \\
        \cline{2-8}
        3  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a} & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\ 
        \cline{2-8}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image]

It seems that there is a higher bottom margin. How can I center the image vertically (and also the text as it seems that the text is too low)?

Comment: Add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`to your preamble and add the option `valign=c` to your `includegraphics` commands. See also: [How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19080/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always suggest `\cmidrule` from `booktabs`, since it adds a nice amount of vertical spacing. Here the trick is to lower a bit the graphics:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\lowincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \raisebox{-0.7\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
  c
  m{0.3\textwidth}
  *{6}{c}
}
Index & Figure & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla\\
\cmidrule{2-8}
1 & \lowincludegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
\cmidrule{2-8}
1 & \lowincludegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
\cmidrule{2-8}
1 & \lowincludegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
\cmidrule{2-8}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all three answers/comments @egreg, Bernard, leandriis. I tried all three suggestions. The comment from leandriis is incorporated in the answer from Bernard. Finally, I decided to combine the answers. Now I use ’\cmidrule’ together with the suggestions from Bernard. The suggestions from leandriis' comment alone center the figure but without space and I would prefer some more space as by Bernard's and egreg's solutions. So, thanks again for your help and useful suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition: replace the 2nd column specifier `m{0.3\textwidth}` with `Sc`, where `S` is a pre-column specifier defined by package `cellspace` which ensures a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in the column, and load `adjustbox`. If you load `siunitx`
, which already defines  an `S` column type, replace `S` with `C`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{m{0.06\textwidth}Sc m{0.05\textwidth} *{6}{m{0.05\textwidth}}}
        Index & Figure & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla\\
        \cline{2-8}
        1 & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth, valign = c]{example-image-a} & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
        \cline{2-8}
        2 & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth, valign = c]{example-image-a} & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
        \cline{2-8}
        3 & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth, valign = c]{example-image-a} & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
        \cline{2-8}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]