# Centering a column vertically with longtable and pictures in rows

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, longtable, vertical

I am having trouble vertically centering the first row to be in the middle of the pictures. I have tried:

1. \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics
2. raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox\relax}
   {\includegraphics
3. \adjustbox{valign=m}

Problem with these were that they had no vertical empty space left between the rows...do you know how to fix this?

Or should I use another tactic to center the first row?

Thanks a lot guys!

[image: a picture of my output]

```
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c c c r@{}}\toprule
  
  
Var. & Aufnahme & Positionierung & Ausrichtung-Drehung Y & Führung X\&Y & Anschlag X\&Y    \\
\midrule\\[3pt]

1 &      {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/LV1.jpeg}}
      &  {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/IMG_6228.jpg}}  
      &  
      &  
      & \\
      
      
      
      
2 &      {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/LV2.jpeg}}
      &  {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/IMG_6235.jpg}} 
      &  
      &  
      & \\
      
      
      
3 &      {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/LV3.jpeg}}
      &  {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/IMG_6236.jpg}}
      &  
      &  
      & \\





4 &      {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/LV4.jpeg}}
      &  
      &  
      &  
      & \\



5 &      {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/LV5.jpeg}}
      &  
      &  
      &  
      & \\
      
      
      
6 &      {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/LV6.jpeg}}
      &  
      &  
      &  
      & \\
      
      
7 &     {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/LV7.jpeg}}&  &  &  & \\
8 &     {\includegraphics[width=1in]{Projekte/LV8.jpeg}}&  &  &  & \\
      
     
      \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try with the `cellspace`package, which lets  you define *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or  `C` if you load `siunitx`).

Comment: @GiovanniGorza -- please see if the answer meets the requirement -- you could off course experiment with the `textwidth` and `linewidth` to taste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of `adjustbox` packages is just fine. Assuming that all columns except the first contain images of the same width, then your table can be written as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\adjustboxset{width=0.17\linewidth,valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
Var.    &   Aufnahme 
            &   Positionierung 
                &   \makecell{Ausrichtung-\\Drehung Y} 
                    &   \makecell{Führung\\ X\&Y} 
                        &   \makecell{Anschlag\\ X\&Y}    \\
\toprule
1 & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
  & \adjustimage{}{example-image-b} 
  & \adjustimage{}{example-image-c} 
  & %\adjustimage{}{example-image}    
  & %\adjustimage{}{example-image}  
  \\
2 & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
  & \adjustimage{}{example-image-b}
  & \adjustimage{}{example-image-c}
  & \adjustimage{}{example-image}
  & \adjustimage{}{example-image}
  \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

In cases, when last five columns in the table not contain images, those columns will adopt to cells content.

Comment: that worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Does this serve the purpose -- as adapted from --

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457216/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\lowincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \raisebox{-0.7\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
  c
  m{0.4\textwidth}
  m{0.4\textwidth}
}
Index & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Figure1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Figure2} \\
\toprule
1 & \lowincludegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
  & \lowincludegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```